# how to define bluetooth version a system support

Tags: android, bluetooth, version, bluez

1. `Bluetooth 4.0` is same as `Bluetooth 4.0 LE`? , i.e. iPhone4s supports bluetooth 4.0, 
   does that mean iPhone4s supports bluetooth 4.0 LE ?
   I know that `bluetooth 3.0` != `bluetooth 3.0 HS`
2. My android phone project, msm7225A platform, bluetooth chip is WCN2243. 
   which version can be defined?
3. In short,  from hardware and software aspects, how to confirm Bluetooth version 
   (when using bluez stack, and take android phone for an example)

it is really a problem that confusing me for a long time.
appreciate anyone give some help.

Comment: I'm just familiar with bluetooth, from the client view, but why does that matter?

Comment: If you are looking to know `BlueZ` version running on Linux, you can issue `bluetoothd -v` to know version.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I got your questions correctly, but maybe this helps:

1. Bluetooth 4.0 specifies two modes of operation: "classic" Bluetooth and "Bluetooth Low Energy (LE)". iPhone 4S's Bluetooth is dual mode, i.e. it supports both classic & LE. IOS, though, only supports programming the latter (LE) directly via the public CentralManager API. There is no way to directly access the "classic" Bluetooth stack in IOS.
2. The standard Android SDKs only support classic Bluetooth. If you want to use LE, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995551/bluetooth-low-energy-bluetooth-4-0-with-android-linux) suggests to use a manufacturer API.
3. BlueZ supports LE's GATT server at least. I haven't worked with that though, so I can't tell how complete LE support is. If you're about to use BlueZ directly on Android phones, mind that this will only work if the user has `root` access.

To answer more generally, LE could/should also have been published without calling it "Bluetooth" at all. So to determine if the hardware/software supports classic and/or LE, you'll have to look at the specs for each platform you're targeting.